# Php error display blank page

Tags: php, error-handling, silex

I've just started using Silex framework. I put error in route

```
$app->get('/hello', function() {
    return 'Hello!';x
});
```

but when I open `/hello` I don't get any errors, I've try to put:

```
error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_WARNING | E_PARSE | E_NOTICE);
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
```

and

```
$app['debug'] = true;
```

But all I get is blank page.

Comment: What about your error log, does that say anything?

Comment: @Ma'moonAl-Akash yes I have error in log `PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '}' in <PATH>/index.php on line 14`

Comment: I have added my answer, check it and hope to solve your issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `x` causes an `E_PARSE` error at the parser level that will stop the parsing/execution immediately, thus the white page.

`E_PARSE` is uncatchable, whenever you get a white page is probably because of it and you should check the error log to locate the source of the error.

Comment: Yes it seams that when I put undefined variable `return 'Hello!' . $x;` I get the error.

Answer (score -1):

Insert the following code at the top of your bootstrap.php **before initialize your $app**:

```
// set the error handling
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
error_reporting(-1);
ErrorHandler::register();
if ('cli' !== php_sapi_name()) {
  ExceptionHandler::register();
}
```

and set

```
$app['debug'] = true;
```

You can also [define your own error handlers as described in the documentation](http://silex.sensiolabs.org/doc/usage.html#error-handlers).

Answer (score -2):

There are many ways to debug your code in this case:

1. [Silex web Profiler](https://github.com/silexphp/Silex-WebProfiler)
2. You might want to check your server error and access logs.

I would first go to the second option cause its much easier and faster to get a quck glimp about what is going on.

Hope this helps for your case

BTW i think i cought an error in your code, what does that "x" doing in your first code segment? in line:

```
return 'Hello!';x
```

Comment: I didn't say it work. I still have blank page instead of error.

Comment: Post your whole code and post the related error log messgaes.

Comment: I put x that is syntax error into hello world example and want to have that error on the page instead of blank page. it's default code from Silex.

Comment: If you have a syntax error then you are in your own, can't provide help for this.